# React-apollo caching of paginated queries (list of items)

Tags: reactjs, caching, react-apollo

I have a paginated query that returns a list of items...

query snippet:

```
const MY_POTENTIAL_VOTERS = gql`
  query potentialVoters(...) {
    potentialVoters(...) 
     {
      items {
        id
        ....
      }
      pageInfo {
        nextCursor
        totalCount
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

In react I then map over the data.potentialVoters.items and render them to UI. The UI then allows an action that will perform a mutation against one of the items in the page.

Mutation snippet:

```
const ASSOCIATE_PV_VOTER = gql`
  mutation updatePotentialVoter($pv_id: String!, $voter_id: String) {
    updatePotentialVoter(id: $pv_id, data: { state_file_id: $voter_id }) {
      id
      ...
    }
  }
`;
```

When exploring the devtools it appears the cache for the affected item is updating correctly with the mutated info, however that row UI (from the page query) does not update as I might expect. Even with using refetchQueries option even them sometimes the mutation is not reflected in the list render, unless I hard refresh.

I have figured out one work around to my problem but I suspect it may not be a good idea.  If my page query passes down just the ID of the item to a separate component which in turns uses it’s own query to get the data for that item, I **think** it is making smart use of the cache and everything updates as expected, but that seems like an anti-pattern that may lead to double fetching.

Might I be doing something wrong with the way I am performing the paginated query that does not allow a react update if a list member item is updated in cache? Is my workaround a really bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the page query from using Apollo HOC to the new Query component and that seems to fix everything. I was able to then use the update prop of the Mutation component to overwrite the mutatated object in the array of page items, which now causes my page to update as expected.